# Complexity of unbalanced bipartite isomorphism

Tags: time-complexity, graph-isomorphism

For $i=1,2$, let $G_i=(A_i\cup B_i,E_i)$ be an undirected bipartite 
graph with bipartition $A_i$ and $B_i$, where $|A_1|=|A_2|=a$ and 
$|B_1|=|B_2|=b$ with $a\le b$.

> **Question.** Is the problem of deciding isomorphism between 
>   such graphs solvable in $O(b^k 2^a)$ time, for some constant $k>0$?

Note that Babai's result yields a $2^{(\log(a+b))^c}$ time 
algorithm for some constant $c>1$. 
For the cases with $a=O(\log b)$, a solution to my question would
yield a polynomial time complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to relax the 2 to some other constant, then yes: this can be solved in $O(c^a)$ time for some absolute constant $c$. You can view this problem as isomorphism of hypergraphs, where the vertices in $A_i$ are the vertices of your hypergraph, and the vertices in $B_i$ are hyperedges. [Luks (STOC '99)](https://doi.org/10.1145/301250.301427) showed how to solve hypergraph isomorphism for hypregraphs on $a$ vertices in $O(c^a)$ time for some absolute constant $c$.

Comment: Well there should be some $b$ dependence even though $a$ dominates in this complexity since $a\leq b$.

Comment: Perhaps corollaries $1.4$ and $5.1$ are relevant?

Comment: The dependence on $b$ is only $b^k$ (possible even just linear in $b$, but I'd have to think a little more about that). Since $b \leq 2^a$ WLOG (otherwise there are two vertices in $B_i$ with identical neighborhoods, which we can collapse and keep track of their multiplicity by a small additional piece of data), we get that $b^k \leq c^a$ for some constant $c$.